# Three JS, WebGl, display sprite on top of panorama

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite

I'm building a simple panorama webapp, where a user will be able to turn in circles and click on sprites in the loaded panorama. I have this working in CSS3D using three.js, now I need to get it to work in WebGL. I've loaded the panorama, and a sprite must be getting added to the scene since there are no errors, but I can't see the sprite.

How do I make it visible?

Here's the relevant code (omitting all the standard event functions and the rendering loop):

```
function init() {

    var container, mesh;

    container = document.getElementById('container');

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100);
    camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var sides = [
        {
            url: '/assets/posx.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/negx.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/posy.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/negy.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/posz.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: '/assets/negz.jpg'
        }
    ];

    var k = 8
    for (var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {

        var side = sides[ i ];
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, k, k);
        k += 8;
        geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(side.url)
        });
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);

    }

    var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("/assets/soap.png");
    material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: map, color: 0xffffff, fog: false });
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);

    sprite.position.x = 128;
    sprite.position.y = 128;
    sprite.position.z = 128;

    scene.add(sprite);


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();


    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken your sphere has a radius of `5` while your sprite is positioned way beyond the sphere at `128,128,128`. You need to either increase your sphere radius or reduce your sprite position to something that lies within the radius.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(256, k, k);
```